# Autofac: How to resolve all generic interfaces of a class

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have such an hierarchy here:

```
public interface I<out T>
{
    T GetItem();
}

public class C : I<Item1>, I<Item2>
{
    Item1 I<Item1>.GetItem() => new Item1();
    Item2 I<Item2>.GetItem() => new Item2();
}

public interface IItem { string Name { get; } }
public class Item1 : IItem { public string Name => "i1"; }
public class Item2 : IItem { public string Name => "i2"; }
```

The main point is that the class C implements two forms of a generic covariant interface.

I want autofac to return me a single instance of the class C twice when I resolve a common interface: `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<I<IItem>>>()`. How to achieve this?

BTW, .NET resolves `(C as I<IItem>).GetItem()` as `I<Item1>.GetItem()`,
even `((I<IItem>)(C as I<Item2>)).GetItem() == "i1"`

Comment: Maybe the question could be simplified. Suppose we have just two simple non-generic interfaces I1, I2 derived from a common interface I, and a class C implementing them both. How to get two instances of C in `IEnumerable<I>` with autofac, the first as I1 and the second as I2 ?  
(although this is not what I need, I guess it may help solve the original question).

Comment: Also, I know that I can find (or resolve) all the concrete types `TItem` derived from `IItem`, resolve `IEnumerable<I<TItem>>` for each of them and then concat the results, but I think, it's the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that the question is out of sense. The main idea was to get an instance of C twice in a `IEnumerable<I<IItem>>` **and** to have `GetItem()` giving `Item1` for the first item, and `Item2` for the second. But it's impossible, .NET types do not work that way. Sorry for confusing. Correct me, please, if I'm wrong.